# $(\sin(\frac{\pi }{3})+i \cos(\frac{\pi }{3}))^8$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Express $(\sin(\frac{\pi }{3})+i \cos(\frac{\pi }{3}))^8$ in $a+bi$
> form.

I used demoivre's, so I got $\sin\left(\frac{8\pi}{3}\right)+i \cos \left(\frac{8\pi}{3}\right)$, does that yield my answer upon evaluation?

Comment: It is the right method to avoid a convoluted binomial developments. Now, you can go further by computing $\cos(8\pi/3)$ and $\sin(8\pi/3)$ using trigonometric identities and the known expressions of $\cos(\pi/3)$ and $\sin(\pi/3)$.

Comment: I've edited your question: there's no need for `\left` and `\right` when using simple brackets `()`, only when using curly brackets `{}`, as those have a special meaning in LaTeX notation.

Comment: There is a good use for the left and right commands, even with simple brackets, in that it automatically enforces sizing of nested braces: $\left((\frac{\pi}{3}) + i \cos(\frac{\pi}{3})\right)^8$

Answer (score 4):

You need to be careful:  DeMoivre's theorem says

$$(\color{red}{\cos} \theta + i \color{blue}{\sin} \theta)^n = \cos n \theta + i \sin n \theta.$$

Note that what you have instead is $$(\color{blue}{\sin} \theta + i \color{red}{\cos} \theta)^n.$$

So what you need to do first is find a way to switch the cosine and sine in your expression.  One way to do this is to note that
$$\cos\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right) = \sin \theta,$$
and similarly,
$$\sin\left(\tfrac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right) = \cos \theta.$$
So what does this do to your expression?  Alternatively, you may observe
$$(\sin \theta + i \cos \theta)^n = i^n (-i \sin \theta + \cos \theta)^n = i^n (\cos (-\theta) + i \sin (-\theta))^n.$$

In any case, after you perform the switch to get the correct form to apply DeMoivre's theorem, you will then want to evaluate $\cos n\theta$ and $\sin n\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

De moivre's theorem only works for complex numbers of the form $$\cos\theta + i\sin\theta$$
So we need to convert $\sin\theta + i\cos\theta$ to $\cos\theta + i\sin\theta$

We know that $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right) = \sin\theta$$ and
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right) = \cos\theta$$

So

$$\sin\theta + i\cos\theta = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \theta\right) $$

Substituting $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$

$$ 
\left(\sin \frac{\pi}{3} + i \cos \frac{\pi}{3} \right)^8 
= \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{3}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right) $$$$ 
= \left( \cos \frac{\pi}{6} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{6} \right)^8 
$$

Now we can apply de moivre's theorem

$$ = \cos \frac{8\pi}{6} + i\sin \frac{8\pi}{6}$$
$$ = \cos \frac{4\pi}{3} + i\sin \frac{4\pi}{3}$$
$$ = -\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2} + i \left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) $$
$$ = -\frac{\sqrt{1}}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $$

Comment: In your displayed equations above the sentence *Hence applying...*, all you seem to have accomplished is to give a complicated proof that $$\sin \theta + i \cos \theta = \sin \theta + i \cos \theta$$

Comment: Thank you for noticing that . I was wracking my brain trying to figure out how I got that $$\sin\theta + i\cos\theta = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$$